# unable to run comet sample code in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, comet, glassfish-3

Hi. I am trying to run Slideshow which is a comet sample code and i have downloaded it from 
[here](http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/restfulcomet/slideshowProject.zip) but when I am trying to run that sample code, I am getting following error at the time of deployment.

I am using Glassfish Server 3 & i have enabled the comet support.

```
SEVERE: WebModule[/slideshow]Error loading WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1258)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:444)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:308)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:94)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: WebModule[/slideshow]PWC1396: Servlet /slideshow threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1258)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:444)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:308)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:94)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: PWC1306: Startup of context /slideshow failed due to previous errors
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:444)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:308)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:94)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1258)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
        ... 46 more

WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:444)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:308)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:94)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:444)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:308)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:94)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using V3...
Sounds like you hit [GLASSFISH-9728](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-9728).

Try either upgrading to [GF 3.1](http://glassfish.java.net/) or adding [grizzly-cometd.jar](http://grizzly.java.net/) and other dependencies to the GF V3 classpath. Check the bug report comments for the modified pom file if you wish to download dependencies from central maven repository.

Comment: grizzly-comet.jar is already there in C:\glassfish3\glassfish\modules but i can;t see pom file anywhere

Comment: Click in the bug report link and click in the comments tab.

Comment: I have tried upgrading glassfish 3.1 but the problem remain same :(

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you then. It clearly states that `com.sun.grizzly.cometd.servlet.CometdServlet` can't be loaded... So, you must experiment with the jar files and Classloaders somehow in order to debug the problem.

Comment: I have found the jar file here is the link http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/archive-details/com/sun/grizzly/cometd/1.6.1/cometd-1.6.1.jar

by adding it into build path one can run this sample successfully

Comment: Quite a comeback hehehe :). I'm glad to be of service. Grizzly has been through a lot of development and active refactoring... You can find CometdServlet at [1.9 Javadocs](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/1.9/apidocs/). [2.0](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/apidocs/) don't even declare `com.sun` packages anymore.

Comment: so what do you suggest , do i need to follow that slideshow example for further development or i need to upgrade something ?

Comment: You can run the old API samples with 1.6.1. Then take a look at the [current documentation](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.0/html/grizzly-docs.html). It shouldn't be that hard to map things around (but will definitively take some effort... Think about Python 2 vs 3).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4388/discussion-between-anthony-accioly-and-hunt)